# ClassCastException with Tomcat and JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm working on a website with Java Servlets and JSPs. I'm running it on tomcat. 
One of my JSP's makes use of a custom class called Message. I set an arraylist messages in a servlet and then try to access it in my JSP, using request.getAttribute() 
If I print the Messages to the console, it works. However, when I try to make use of them on my website I get an exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Message cannot be cast to classes.Message
org.apache.jsp.html.Chatroom_jsp._jspService(Chatroom_jsp.java:137)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:4 
53)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
MessageServlet.doGet(MessageServlet.java:67)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Steps I have taken: put a page import on top of jsp, added the class to web-inf/classes and added the classes to catalina.properties. But still its not working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
 %>
 <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="classes.Message"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Chat Messages</h2>

<table>
<!-- dynamically generate the messages here  -->
<tr>
    <th>user</th>
    <th>message</th>
    <th>time</th>
</tr>

<%

    //set the messages into an arraylist
    ArrayList <Message> msgs = new ArrayList<Message>();
    msgs = (ArrayList) request.getAttribute("messages");
    //TEST OUTPUT, to check if we can access messages
    System.out.println("hi. this is the message");
    System.out.println(msgs.get(0));
    //Message mess = new Message();
    //mess.setMessage(msgs.get(0).getMessage());
    //mess.setTime(msgs.get(0).getTime());
    //mess.setUserId(msgs.get(0).getUserId());
    //mess.setFname(msgs.get(0).getFname());

    for(Message mess : msgs)
    {
        %>
        <td><%=mess.getFname() %></td>
        <td><%=mess.getMessage() %></td>
        <td><%=mess.getTime() %></td>
        <%
    }

%>  


</table>


<form>
<div class="container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter message here " name="userPost" required>
      <button onClick = 'myFunction(); return false' type="submit">Submit</button>
    <p id = "demo"></p>

</div>
</form>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = "Hello";
}

// Get the modal
var model = document.getElementById('id01');

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you import your Message class at top of your jsp file? `<%@page import="path.to.your.class"%>`

Comment: Yes I did import it on top of the jsp

Comment: please add your jsp code too

Comment: Just did. thank you. please note that the test output for the messages does work, but the for loop is where I get an exception

Comment: It's really strange! try to not use foreach and tell me what happen: `for(int i = 0; i< msgs.size(); i++)  <td><%=msgs[i].getFname() %></td>`

Comment: Before your `for loop, try adding `application.log("Message is of type " + msgs.get(0).getClass().getName());`. Perhaps the type isn't what you were expecting it to be. In your `Message` class, what does the `package` declaration say?

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort, I really do appreciate the help. I changed it to a regular for loop, but I kept it as an arraylist, not an array(not sure if you were suggesting that, so I did msgs.get(i).getFName() ) and I am still getting this error

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz. Thanks! I tried adding in that line, and surprisingly that line threw the exception! In the message class I looked and I see that I dont have a package declaration. Maybe that's the issue. What should the package be? (if my message class is in. WEB-INF/classes/Message)

Comment: @SGolds your error says `org.apache.jsp.html.Chatroom_jsp._jspService(Chatroom_jsp.java:137)` in line you are getting casting error ! In your code which line is 137 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `import` declaration incorrect. The fully-qualified class name of your class is simple `Message`, not `classes.Message`.

So, your import line should look like this:

```
<%@page import="Message"%>
```

But! You can't import a class without a package... the above fill cause a compiler error.

So, what you *really* have to do is move your `Message` class from the so-called "default package" (i.e. *no package*) into a package. You do that in two steps:

1. Add a `package` declaration to your class, like this:

   package sgolds;

   public class Message
   ...
2. Move `Message.java` from `src/Message.java` to `src/sgolds/Message.java`

Now recompile your .java files.

Now, update your JSP to have the correct `import`:

```
<%@page import="sgolds.Message"%>
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: YAY!! It worked! I can't believe that that was the problem. (slightly embarrassed) At some point of my debuggin I had made a seperate package for the Message class, but I think when I did it it didn't work because I was using a package that was already used somewhere else. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: This is one part of the JSP spec that is very surprising to newcomers. In practice, all classes should *always* be in a package because the "default package" is not always addressable (as in this case).